# Reading .pch file in static library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am creating a static library and adding all the project files which I want to expose to other projects. Now, I have a .pch file which contains most of my #import statements which is to be used throughout the application.

When compiling this static library I am getting errors because of these missing import statements. I tried copying the .pch file in "Copy header" as well as "Copy source" but it did not work.

Any clue how to add a .pch file in a static library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the project build settings, and search for "pch".  There's an item called "Prefix Header" where you can enter the name of your PCH file.

Comment: Don't search for "pch". Search for "Prefix Header".